# How to add a correction to a line of text, as if reviewing a hard-copy of a paper and found a word missing?

Tags: superscripts

I want to add a correction to a line, as one would write if they were going through a hard-copy of a paper and found that a word was omitted.  I've drawn by hand specifically what I'm after below:

[image: correction made by hand]

The original line should be unchanged.

I'm guessing there's a simple way of doing this (e.g. some package), but I don't know how to do it, and I'm not sure what to search for.  (I'm also unsure what to tag this question.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Output $(I_1) = D$

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I need to do correctios as you in LaTeX, I use the [`todonotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) pakage that allows create a lot of different notes for further revisions and also create a list of thigs to do. Using it with hyperrref is very comfortable, you could try.

Comment: You might check the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615738/adding-ms-word-like-comments-in-latex

Comment: Unlike @Aradnix I didn't get on with `todonotes` in this application.  Instead I used the rather simpler [`changes` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changes).  It does reflow your text, which you say you don't want, but you may well find you need mutliline insertions which wouldn't work too well with your approach. I also had a couple of custom macros used for adding specific notes (e.g. a wikipedia-style "citation needed") which I could search for in the .pdf to make sure I had done them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very simple-minded solution based on my above comments.  If these omitted words and so on turn into whole clauses and setences, then you might want a more robust solution.  As it is, some care is taken to not affect the existing layout of the paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\correction[1]{%
  \unskip
  \begingroup \tiny
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{1\baselineskip}[0pt]{\bfseries [#1]}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}[0pt]{$\wedge$}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Output \correction{from}
 $(I_1) = D$

Output  $(I_1) = D$ I want to add a correction to a line, as one would 
write if they were going through a hard-copy of a paper and found that a 
word
\correction{was} 
omitted. I've drawn by hand specifically what I'm after below:

Output  $(I_1) = D$ I want to add a correction to a line, as one would
write if they were going through a hard-copy of a paper and found that a 
word omitted. I've drawn by hand specifically what I'm after below:

Output \correction{from}
 $(I_1) = D$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

My approach is a colored flag for better readability. As I think that there are no reason  to maintain the interline spacing in a draft version, the flag is enough tall to avoid overlapping corrections with the ascenders characters of the text (anyway is fairly simple shorten the flag if this is also required).

[image: mWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\fboxsep.6pt
\def\Add#1{\rlap{\hskip-.15em\color{blue!70}\vrule\raisebox%
{.7\baselineskip}{\fcolorbox{blue!10}{blue!05}{\tiny#1}}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
    Put a litle \Add{flag} whenever \Add{you} need.\par
    Output \Add{from} $(I_1) = D$
\end{document}
```